# Unable to update [PFUser currentUser] when Public Updated Disabled

Tags: facebook, security, parse-platform

I'm recently trying to lock down security on a parse project and have disabled except for public create.

[image: User Security / Permissions]

However after doing so if I try and link an existing user to Facebook as follows:

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser] permissions:nil block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) { /* ... */ }];
```

I see the following error printed on console:

```
2015-02-04 00:11:19.856 Walker[43201:381190] Error: This user is not allowed to perform the update operation on _User. You can change this setting in the Data Browser. (Code: 119, Version: 1.5.0)
```

This is despite the current user having read / write permissions to itself:

[image: Individual User Permissions]

If I enable public 'Updates' for the User class again this problem goes away? 
Is there any way I can enable updates on the current user without enabling public access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the following answer from Hector Ramos on the Parse Google Group ( https://groups.google.com/d/msg/parse-developers/JFMrXheHgdo/1dw_6dl1EmUJ )

> In order to link a user to Facebook, the user object must be modified.
>   You'll need to turn on Updates for this class. Per-object ACLs cannot
>   increase the scope of permissions past what the class-level ACLs are
>   providing, as far as I know.

I took this to mean that I had to enable Updates for the class in order for any update to be made at all.

I still was a little concerns this could some how allow unauthorized updates to my user account (as this answer wasn't 100% clear). To be on the safe side, I also added a CloudCode before save hook which sets the users Access Control List (ACL) to only allow them access to this object (as per my apps requirements).

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    // Set ACL for new User to only that user 
    request.object.setACL(new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()));
    response.success();
});
```